# url tag - want to pass in reversible variable

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using passing a variable into my view to use with the `url` tag:

```
{% load url from future %}
...
{% if notification.url %}
  <a href='{% url notification.url %}'>{% notification.text %}</a>
{% endif %}
```

`notification.url` is set to something like `post`, the name of the url I wish to point to, however the url isn't reversed, as `{% url 'post' %}` would be.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rubber ducked](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html) this one half way through writing it.

The solution is to just use `reverse()` on the url name before passing it to the template.